# Open PDF in C# as view only without adobe

Tags: c#, pdf

im needing to create a form in my C# project that just allows the user to view the pdf.

i have a way to open the pdf and read it but i need to disable features like printing, saving, highlighting, copy/pasting while maintaining the ability to search in the document

they should really just be able to open the document, read it,search for words in the document, close it

any help would be great
thanks in advanced

Comment: _i have a way to open the pdf and read it but i need to disable features_ So, what is your way to open and read the PDF in c#?

Comment: You will need third party library to view PDF if you wish not using Adobe. you will need to supply that DLL with you software which is much less trouble than asking user to install adobe. There is a couple of good one for Winforms and WPF out there. Look for it that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert PDF to images and then show the images on your form or you could rasterize your PDF directly to the screen.

To use **Ghostscript** from **.NET** you can take a look at the [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) library (managed wrapper around the Ghostscript library).

Ghostscript **Viewer** C# sample that rasterizes PDF directly to the screen can be found here: **https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/tree/master/Ghostscript.NET.Viewer**

To search for the text inside the pdf you can use **[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)**

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer I worked on this component at Software Siglo XXI)*

If you don't want to mess with Ghostscript API and need a quick working solution to visualise the documents, you could use **ImageZoom Viewer .NET**. It's available for both 32 and 64 bit and is very cheap and effective. I'd recommend you to try it since it's a very fancy and fast. You can browse, scroll and print the pages from the viewer.

You can take a look here: http://softwaresigloxxi.com/ImageZoom.html

This is for quick browsing and reading. Then, when you want to use text operations, you could let the user to use Adobe Reader, launching the PDF from there.